# Swift 4.2 - Creating a a UILabel object programmatically

Tags: swift, macos

Silly question here, but I recently updated my Xcode and decided to give swift 4.2 a chance. However, I'm having trouble creating a UILabel (programmatically). Everything I find online refers to creating labels using NStextField. But if thats the case how do I go about making immutable and un-selectable? 
Btw this is a macOS project. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `UILabel` is part of `UIKit` which is available only on iOS.

Comment: Just realized when working with NSTextField all you have to do is set "isEditable" to false, thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on NSDmitry's comment:

Any object who's class name starts with "UI..." belongs to `UIKit`, which is iOS only. As such, `UILabel` is an iOS only object.

As you've figured out you need to set `isEditable` to false on an `NSTextField`. You might want to set `isSelectable` to false as well, unless you want the user to be able to drag to select the text.